# Retrieving embed domain settings through YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube Data API seems to allow you to get the embeddable status of the video: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/VideoStatus.html#getEmbeddable()

But there is also a feature in youtube where the content owners can set the video to be embeddable (or not embeddable) on certain domains: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625

In this case, the embeddable status returned by the YouTube API is insufficient and can be misleading. For a video id (example: TZ82ZR70vcc) which seems to have domain based embeddable settings, the embeddable status returns true, however, it not true for all domain.

Is there a way to retrieve the embed domain settings? Or to check if the video is embeddable on a given domain or not?

Comment: I'm not used to use Youtube as a channel owner, if you do, I suggest you look how embeddable settings is configurated, and, based on the values you set there, check if you find the matching values on API's fields (use API Explorer for Youtube Data). As far as I could see, you have only embeddable true/false (regardless the domain)

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube blog on [Understanding Playback Restrictions](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions_28.html) states that

> if you’d like to only search for videos that are embeddable, add
>   `format=5` to your query.

So add a &format=5 to your Youtube Data URL.

You may also read this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857495/how-can-i-tell-if-a-youtube-video-is-embeddable-before-i-try-and-load-it) for additional insight.