# Why I can not show some youtube url in laravel 8 app?

Tags: laravel, youtube-iframe-api

I need to show youtube url in laravel 8 app. I found branch [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options#answer-7469997)
and using it I made in my blade file :

I got this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjqzftaWkmg video
and added on my form :

```
    <div class="tab-pane container mt-3" id="youtubeTabPane">
        <div class="col-12 form-group">
            <label class="w-100 mb-0"><span class="d-block mb-1"> Youtube</span>
                ::{{ old('youtube_url', $news->youtube_url) }}
            </label>
            <input
                class="form-control"
                name="youtube_url"
                value="{{ old('youtube_url', $news->youtube_url) }}"
            />


            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{ old('youtube_url', $news->youtube_url) }}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>
    </div>
```

as a parameter I got error message : https://prnt.sc/ky8JRP6CI97T But clicking the “Watch on youtube” valid video on is opened.

I copypasted code from small video lesson at link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly36kn0ug4k and this copypasted code visible ok : https://prnt.sc/BpLP4efWSYlI

The code of these 2 iframes :

```
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xjqzftaWkmg" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture;" allowfullscreen></iframe>


                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ly36kn0ug4k" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So some youtube videos are rendered ok, some not.

I suppose these are some youtube video props, which I could not find...

Comment: YouTube users can forbid their videos from being embedded. YouTube will also prevent age-restricted or private videos from being embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Laravel. If you open the links `https://www.youtube.com/embed/xjqzftaWkmg`, you will see the link does not work. But for other links like `https://www.youtube.com/embed/ly36kn0ug4k` it does work. This is a property of the YouTube video itself. As a content creator on YouTube, you can restrict others from embedding the video - see https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625?hl=en

So for the videos where it is not being embedded, it is possibly restricted by the content creator.

Comment: Thanks! Checking both mentioned vieo I can open Embed Video dialog and do not see any difference.
If there is a way to define if content creator restricted this videos from embedding ?

Comment: Check this StackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899387/how-do-i-use-the-youtube-api-to-check-if-a-video-is-embeddable